# Flink Dashboard Throughput doesn't add up

Tags: apache-flink, dashboard, metrics

I have two operators, a source and a map. The incoming throughput of of the map is stuck at just above 6K messages/s whereas the message count reaches the size of the whole stream (~ 350K) in under 20s (see duration). 350000/20 means that I have a throughput of at least 17500 and not 6000 as flink suggests! What's going on here?

as shown in the picture:

start time = 13:10:29

all messages are already read by = 13:10:46 (less than 20s)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the flink library code and it seems that the numRecordsOutPerSecond statistic (as well as the rest similar ones) operate on a window. This means that they display average throughput but of the last X seconds. It's not the average throughput of the whole execution